# Bind DNS server is not starting just page got refreshed, why?

Tags: bind

I have webmin CP and have installed BIND DNS server. When I click Start BIND link on upper right corner of the page nothing happens, just my page got refreshed? Is this normal or should I see STOP link rather than Start link?

**EDIT:**

I typed `service named status`  in terminal and got something as below:

```
rndc:neither etc/endc.conf nor etc/rndc.key was found  
named dead but subsys locked
```

And now I have the following:

```
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
named dead but subsys locked
```

New things happened after clicking setup rndc (service named status):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Update:I think you can configure the missing rndc stuff from the webmin BIND DNS server module page like so;

[image]

configuring webmin BIND chroot options;

[image]

Comment: That should setup the etc/rndc.conf file, and get you to the next step.

Comment: Oh, if you have a chroot then you need to make sure that the webmin (and package installed) files are synchronised to your chroot. This is beyond my experience. I can see an chroot option in the webmin module configuration which might help webmin put the generated keys in the right place

Comment: I would suggest getting it working without the chroot, and migrating the working configuration into a chroot afterwards. Its hard to tell which the issue is under the circumstances, because you would need to provide all your webmin/chroot/bind configurations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3489/discussion-between--and-tom-h)